# Не понимаю, как сделать рекурсию

Tags: python, строки, рекурсия

Если первый элемент равен последнему, то возвращается True, если нет, то False

```
def True_or_False(s:str):
    if s[0] == s[-1]:
       return True
    return False
```

Comment: Я ничего не понял. `return s[0] == s[-1]`

Comment: @Igor это условие проверяет равен ли первый элемент последнему -
например, если s = "aga", то функция вернетTrue

Comment: При таком описании условия никакой рекурсии и вообще продолжения обработки не требуется

Comment: какой-то странный вопрос, замените string на str, пожалуйста

Comment: Может быть, речь идёт о палиндромах?

Answer (score 1):

Если задача - проверить, является ли строка палиндромом, то рекурсия может выглядеть примерно так:

```
 if len(s) < 2:
     return True
 if s[0] == s[-1]:
     return True_or_False(s[1:-1])
 return False
```